# Specific string use as attribute n XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a String `//hdfhddf/vgbgb/erer/nhnhn//&lt;std-der&gt;/figure.jpg`. I want to filter only `fig_1.eps` and use it as a attribute in XSLT.

output should be :

```
<image ref="fig_1.eps" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can use XSLT 2.0, I would suggest:

```
tokenize($yourstring, '/')[last()]
```

There is a likely a shorter regex-only option, but I prefer readability.